# Permeability of Nafion membrane

Tags: polymers

[Nafion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafion) membrane is used as a proton exchange membrane (PEM) in fuel cells due to its selectively high permeability to hydronium ions $(\ce{H3O+})$ and water.

A permeability study was done on small organic polar molecules like 1-propanol and d1-propanol and dimethyl methylphosphonate [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp037448h)] showing that those small organic polar molecules can pass through the membrane, however, I can't find anything about bigger molecules like the examples below.

[image: dyes]

#### Questions

1. Is Nafion permeable to polar organic molecules with bigger dimensions than typical solvents?
2. Is Nafion permeable to non-polar organic molecules?

#### References

1. Rivin, D.; Meermeier, G.; Schneider, N. S.; Vishnyakov, A.; Neimark, A. V. Simultaneous Transport of Water and Organic Molecules through Polyelectrolyte Membranes. *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2004**, 108 (26), 8900–8909. DOI: [10.1021/jp037448h](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp037448h).